# How to check bank bonus web page from last year?

Tags: banking, checking-account, bonus, promotion

I opened account in a TD bank. Bank had promotion going on in August 2020. I close account in same bank before 2 years.

Promotion T&C was starts with

> Offer is available to new personal checking Customers who do not have an existing or prior personal checking account at TD Bank within the preceding 12 months, open their account online via this web page and complete the required qualifying criteria.

I didn't get bonus, and then I check with bank. Now they replied that, I had account before 2 years, and that is the reason I am not eligible for bonus. I met the criteria for bonus, but still waiting for bonus :(.

Is there any way to check the bonus web page from bank website in August 2020?

I tried with archive.org, but I was not sure about exact url.

Comment: Lesson to be learned: when taking such an offer, print the offer to PDF and keep it. Learned that the hard way.

Comment: Got the answer `One bonus per account per Customer and cannot be combined with any other offer. ` this was in T&C, and I interpreted it as one bonus for one SSN, means I can't open multiple account and get that bonus. But now they are saying, meaning of this is, *if you have anytime before TD account, you are not eligible :)*

Comment: To answer the question; Internet Archive may have captured the page. But yes, such offers almost always explicitly say "new customers only" where that is defined as "has not had an account with us for at least N years." ALWAYS read the fine print.